# How can I remove the space between my plot and the axis in ggplot2 figures?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 to make some simple figures with a series using coordinates to make rectangles along the x-axis. However, I can't seem to figure out how to remove the padding between the actual start of the plot (x=1 location) and the leftmost edge of the plot, at what would be (0,0). For example, I am using the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
png(filename="sample.png", width=5600, height=70)
plot.data <- data.frame(start.points=c(1),end.points=c(10))
p <- ggplot(plot.data)
p + geom_rect(aes(xmin=start.points, xmax=end.points, ymin=0, ymax=1), fill="red") + theme_bw() + ylab(paste(sprintf("%60s", ""), "\nSample_label\n")) + theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 30, colour = "black", angle = 0))
dev.off()
```

The variables `my_start` and `my_stop` are just lists of start and stop coordinates for drawing rectangles. So, this plot creates a long horizontal figure, just as I want.

The problem is, the figure looks like this:

```
axis_label    | <-- white space --> <-----actual plot------> <-- white space--> |
```

Actual plot:
[image]

...and I want to manually control this amount of `white space`. I've tried setting `plot.margin` and `panel.margin`, but these seem to control other aspects of the plot. Please note, that on my sample picture the red starts at point of 1 as expected. I want this to border the y axis, and I don't want any trailing space after the end of the red bar.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Ideally I would just remove all white space padding. Thanks!

Comment: This problem is not [REPRODUCIBLE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as it contains no data.  Also note that you can upload images.  Thant may be a better way to discuss this topic than the purely text approach.

Comment: I've added a single data point, so it now contains all of the data to reproduce the problem. I've also added a png of the actual plot to illustrate my problem more accurately. Please advise!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to add to add `scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))` to your plot code. From the [**help text**](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/continuous_scale.html):

**expand**: a numeric vector of length two, giving a multiplicative and additive constant used to expand the range of the scales so that there is a small gap between the data and the axes.

```
ggplot(plot.data) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = start.points, xmax = end.points, ymin = 0, ymax = 1), fill = "red") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
```